# Wordpress a template for subcategories fo a given category, but not for root category

Tags: categories, templates

I've found this simple yet elegant solution for make Wordpress using the same template category on every child and grandchild categories 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3117202/391929

Full code:

```
function myTemplateSelect() {
    if (is_category() && !is_feed()) {
        if (is_category(get_cat_id('projects')) || cat_is_ancestor_of(get_cat_id('projects'), get_query_var('cat'))) {
            load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-projects.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'myTemplateSelect');
```

But I still have one problem: in my case the root category (on the above example the "projects" category) should not use the that template, but a different one, so I made this simple change in the snippet:

```
function myTemplateSelect() {
        if (is_category() && !is_feed()) {
            if (cat_is_ancestor_of(get_cat_id('projects'), get_query_var('cat'))) {
                load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-projects-tree.php');
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
```

But for some reason this is not working, can anyone see why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this in a procedural way:

1 added in theme function this snippet:

add_action('template_redirect', 'load_category_tree_template');

```
function load_category_tree_template() {
    if (is_category() && !is_feed()) {
        // replace 'your-base-category-slug' with the slug of root category
        $base_tree_cat_id = get_cat_id('your-base-category-slug'); 
            // get current category id
        $catid = get_query_var('cat'); 

        if (is_category($base_tree_cat_id) || cat_is_ancestor_of($base_tree_cat_id, $catid)) {
            load_template(STYLESHEETPATH . '/category-your-base-category-slug.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in category-your-base-category-slug.php file i include a different other file based on current category slug:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
if (is_category( )) {
  $cat = get_query_var('cat');
  $currentcat = get_category ($cat);
  $currentslug = $currentcat->slug;
 }
// if we are in base category we know it by the slug
if ($currentslug == 'your-base-category-slug'){
        // if we are load a file with the loop for the root category
    require_once('post-loop-caregory-tree-root.php'); 
}else{
        // otherwise we are not in the root, so show the loop for all other category in the tree
    require_once('post-loop-category-tree.php'); 
}
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I know it can be done better, but it's quite simple solution in the end.